# Regex - how to match text between commas

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a text like: "Something, some text between commas, between comma, and more text between commas, something something." I need to match every piece of text that is insides two commas. I found this regex `/,([^,]*),/g`, but it is returning me:

, some text between commas,

, and more text between commas,

**but i need it to return:**

some text between commas

between comma

and more text between commas

Need your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to split the on the comma's (including optional whitespaces).
Then remove the first & last elements of the array.
But that works fine as long those starting & ending comma's aren't required in the resulting array.

**Example snippet:**

```js
var str = "Something, some text between commas, between comma, and more text between commas, something something";

var arr = str.split(/\s*,\s*/).slice(1,-1);

console.log(arr);
```

But if you do need to keep the start&end comma's in the result?
Then matching with a lookahead should do the trick.

**Example snippet:**

```js
var str = "Something, some text between commas, between comma, and more text between commas, something something";

var re = /,[^,]*(?=,)/g;
var arr = [];
var match;
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
   arr.push(match[0]+',');
}

console.log(arr);
```

*(although I don't really see the point to keep those comma's)*

Comment: This includes the "something something" that is not between commas at the end.

Comment: @Boric Hadn't noticed that. Fixed now.

Comment: Looks nice, i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex with a positive lookahead to ensure that the text is between commas without consuming the second comma.

```regex
/,([^,]*)(?=,)/g
```

See here for a working example: https://regexr.com/3qkui

Comment: I am not sure it is relevant, but your results are not in line with OP. OP wants `, some text between commas,` as first match, while you have `, some text between commas` (without the trailing comma).